# Find difference of sum of column for different users

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I want to find out difference of sum of debit and credit transactions of user and list them out.

Here is the query which i have tried out:

```
SELECT *, (val1 - val2)
FROM (SELECT *, sum(transactionAmount) AS val1
      FROM tableTransaction
      WHERE creditedToNum = My_Number
      GROUP BY debtToNum) db
JOIN (SELECT *, sum(transactionAmount) AS val2
      FROM tableTransaction
      WHERE debtToNum = My_Number
      GROUP BY creditedToNum) Cr
WHERE db.transactionStatus = 1
  AND db.isActive = 1;
```

It's returning 0 rows but the actual output should be as below
Here is my table structure:

```
| Amount | Credit_to | Debit_to  |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
| 2000   | My_Number | Number_1  |
| 5000   | My_Number | Number_2  |
| 3000   | Number_1  | My_Number |
| 4000   | Number_2  | My_number |
| 2000   | My_Number | Number_2  |
```

What actual result I want is:

```
| Name     | Amount |
|----------|--------|
| Number_1 | 1000   |
| Number_2 | 3000   |
```

Comment: That query is unreadable. It does not matter how your Java code constructs it; show the actual SQL. And what is the problem with the current query?

Comment: @CL. I have updated my query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no join condition in your query.

Instead of joining, it might be a better idea to use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to bring the data into a useful form:

```
SELECT Credit_to AS Name, Amount
FROM tableTransaction
WHERE Debit_to = @My_Number
UNION ALL
SELECT Debit_to, -Amount
FROM tableTransaction
WHERE Credit_to = @My_Number;
```

```
| Name     | Amount |
|----------|--------|
| Number_1 |  3000  |
| Number_2 |  4000  |
| Number_1 | -2000  |
| Number_2 | -5000  |
| Number_2 | -2000  |
```

Then just group it:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM (SELECT Credit_to AS other, Amount
      FROM tableTransaction
      WHERE Debit_to = @My_Number
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Debit_to AS other, -Amount
      FROM tableTransaction
      WHERE Credit_to = @My_Number)
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

```
| Name     | Total |
|----------|-------|
| Number_1 |  1000 |
| Number_2 | -3000 |
```